# Typescript: Redirect component 'to' prop type error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I got this basic error display component.

It works like this: you enter the page, if you passed a prop 'redirectUrl', you set a 5 second timer and afterwards it triggers the redirect. So this redirectUrl prop is optional.

However when I made my type object it triggers the 'to' prop of Redirect to throw this error:

> No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(props:
> RedirectProps | Readonly): Redirect', gave the
> following error.
> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'LocationDescriptor'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'LocationDescriptor'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(props:
> RedirectProps, context: any): Redirect', gave the following error.
> Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'LocationDescriptor'.ts(2769) index.d.ts(57, 5): The expected
> type comes from property 'to' which is declared here on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes &
> Readonly & Readonly<...>' index.d.ts(57, 5): The
> expected type comes from property 'to' which is declared here on type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes &
> Readonly & Readonly<...>'

How would you avoid this?

**Code:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles, Box, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import { CloseOctagonOutline } from 'mdi-material-ui';
import { Redirect } from "react-router";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    container: {
        minHeight: "100vh",
        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.dark,
    },
    icon: {
        fontSize: theme.spacing(7),
        color: 'red',
        marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    innerContainer: {
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        borderRadius: 12,
        maxWidth: 400,
        width: '80%',
        padding: theme.spacing(3),
    },
    title: {
        marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
    },
    message: {
        marginBottom: theme.spacing(2),
    }
}));

export interface DisplayErrorPageProps {
    message: string,
    title: string,
    redirectUrl?: string,
}

export const DisplayErrorPage = ({ message, title, redirectUrl }: DisplayErrorPageProps) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (redirectUrl) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                setRedirect(true);
            }, 5000);
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            {redirect && <Redirect to={redirectUrl} />}
            <Box
                display="flex"
                justifyContent="center"
                alignItems="center"
                className={classes.container}
            >
                <Box className={classes.innerContainer}>
                    <Box display='flex' justifyContent='center'>
                        <CloseOctagonOutline className={classes.icon} />
                    </Box>
                    <Typography className={classes.title} align='center' variant='h4'>{title}</Typography>
                    <Typography className={classes.message} align='center' variant='body2'>{message}</Typography>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Redirect` component does not accept a `to` prop that can be `undefined`.

So you could update your conditional rendering to check that `redirectUrl` exists, like this:

```
{redirect && redirectUrl ? <Redirect to={redirectUrl} /> : null}
```